# Value error while taking index of a value and finding its corresponding value in an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I'm trying to make an array of tuples with a value of: `vals = [(1,3), (2,2), (3,1)]`.

Later in the code, I would like to take a value from integer variable `x-num`, and find the corresponding value in the `[1]` index in the `vals` array and print that returned value.

The code I tried was: `print(vals.index(x-num)[1])`

I keep getting this error: `"ValueError: 2 is not in list"` (I'm processing x-vals 1,2,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the item at the index which corresponds to `x-num`.

Change

```
print(vals.index(x-num)[1])
```

to

```
print(vals[x-num - 1][1])
```

`x-num - 1` because `list` is indexed from zero in Python.

```
>>> x_vals = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for x in x_vals:
...    print(vals[x-1][1])
3
2
1
```

---

`index()` does something else:

> The index() method returns the index of the specified element in the
> list.

Source: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index

```
>>> vals.index((1,3))
0
```